# Computing size of Window decoration depending on OS with javaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Is there a way to know the thickness of MacOS Window Bars (respectively Windows or any OS) from JavaFX?
[image]

I would like to place multiple windows one below the other.

Comment: Have you tried the `width` and `height` properties of a `Stage`?

Comment: yes, it doesn't take into account this bar.

Comment: At least for windows that are already displayed it should be possible to transform the bounds of the scene root to screen coordinates and compare with the window position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in one of the comments, if `stage` is a stage that is displayed on the screen and has undergone a layout pass, you can do

```
Parent root = stage.getScene().getRoot();
Bounds localRootBounds = root.getBoundsInLocal();
Point2D localRootTopLeft = new Point2D(localRootBounds.getMinX(), localRootBounds.getMinY());
Point2D screenRootTopLeft = root.localToScreen(localRootTopLeft);
```

which gives the top left of the root of the scene in screen coordinates.

Then

```
double stageTopBorderThickness = screenRootTopLeft.getY() - stage.getY();
```

gives the difference between the location of the window and the location of its root node.

Here's a quick demo:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageDecorationThicknessTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(1, 10, 1);
        Button open = new Button("Open Windows");
        open.setOnAction(e -> {
            int numWindows = spinner.getValue() ;
            Parent root = primaryStage.getScene().getRoot();
            Bounds localRootBounds = root.getBoundsInLocal();
            Point2D localRootTopLeft = new Point2D(localRootBounds.getMinX(), localRootBounds.getMinY());
            Point2D screenRootTopLeft = root.localToScreen(localRootTopLeft);
            double stageTopBorderThickness = screenRootTopLeft.getY() - primaryStage.getY() ;

            Stage owner = primaryStage ;
            for (int i = 0 ; i < numWindows ; i++) {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                Button close = new Button("Close");
                close.setOnAction(evt -> stage.hide());
                Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(close), primaryStage.getScene().getWidth(), 80);
                stage.initOwner(owner);
                stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.setX(primaryStage.getX());
                stage.setY(screenRootTopLeft.getY() + i * stageTopBorderThickness);
                stage.show();
                owner = stage ;
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10, spinner, open);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]